# How to close connection with netty CorsHandler

Tags: java, cors, netty

How do you make netty's [CorsHandler](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/cors/CorsHandler.html) close its connection? It closes by default when the origin passes but it does not close when the origin is not allowed. I setup a server like this with the CorsHandler instance.

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMethod;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.cors.CorsConfigBuilder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.cors.CorsHandler;
import io.netty.handler.logging.LogLevel;
import io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler;

/**
 * Runs netty with a CORS handler on 8080
 */
public class NettyCorsApp {
    private static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
                    .group(eventLoopGroup)
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                            pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
                            pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1024 * 1024)); // 1MB
                            pipeline.addLast(new CorsHandler(
                                    CorsConfigBuilder.forOrigin("http://example.com")
                                            .allowedRequestMethods(HttpMethod.POST)
                                            .build())
                            );
                        }
                    })
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
            Channel channel = bootstrap.bind(PORT).sync().channel();
            channel.closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            eventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

When you request from an origin that passes the CORS check, the CorsHandler closes the connection like you would expect.

```
$ curl -sv -X OPTIONS -H 'Origin: http://example.com' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' http://localhost:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://example.com
> Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< access-control-allow-origin: http://example.com
< vary: origin
< access-control-allow-methods: POST
< access-control-allow-headers:
< access-control-max-age: 0
< date: "Tue, 26 Sep 2017 20:03:53 GMT"
< content-length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

But when you request from an origin that does not pass the CORS check, it does not close the connection.

```
$ curl -sv -X OPTIONS -H 'Origin: http://invalid.com' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' http://localhost:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://invalid.com
> Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
<
```

This may be a bug in netty, if so I will submit it there.

Comment: I tested with netty 4.1.6-Final and 4.1.16-Final, same result.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a bug report site, you should report bugs at the netty issues section on github: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues Also, in the top example, netty doesn't close the connection (there is ano connection header present)

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't quite understand connection keep-alive vs close and http 1.0 vs 1.1, but I do now and see what you are talking about. I did track it down to a bug in netty which I submitted here:

https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/7261

I asked here not knowing if it was a bug like I said in my first post. Definitely would not have submitted to SO if I had known it were a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following what @Ferrybig pointed out, `CorsHandler` is not closing the connection intentionally because there is no `Connection: close` header in the request. Http 1.0 assumes the tcp connection should be closed by default and http 1.1 (which curl defafdults to) should stay open by default.

The reason curl did not exit on a bad origin is because `CorsHandler` did not include a `Content-Length` header in its response, which is a bug.

https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/7261